# TypeScript - export default as

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Working on react application in TypeScript.

I'm trying to understand the correct syntax for exporting a default component using `as`

Up till now I've used:

```
class HomePage extends Component<IProps, IState> {
   ...
}

export default HomePage
```

or in shortly:

```
export default class HomePage extends Component<IProps, IState> {
   ...
}
```

now, after adding redux support. I have something like:

```
class HomePage extends Component<IProps, IState> {
   ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => {
   ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
   ...
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

but I can't figure it out how to add `as` to the connect default export
e.g something like:

```
// This is NOT working. I get Syntax error.
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage) as HomePage;
```

is it possible? or should I do it? it's seems that anyway the export name is `HomePage` (when I'm importing `HomePage` in other file, the IDE is automatically detects and import this file). Where is it taken from? the name of the file (`HomePage.tsx`)?

This is do work for me:

```
const connectedHomePage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage)
export {connectedHomePage as HomePage};
```

but it's two lines (I prefer in one line) and it's not a default export.

so, is there a way to `export default` AND adding `as` to the statement? just so it will be clear what is the exported name?

Comment: `export default` always exports as, well, `default`. What are you expecting to get with this syntax?

Comment: @Cerberus to understand how to make sure that when I import this from another file the IDE will recognize this export as `HomePage` and will be able to auto-import it (which it actually does!)
I understood why IDE can recognize `export default class HomePage` as HomePage (`import HomePage from './HomePage'`) but wasn't sure how it can also work for `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);` when I write in another file `HomePage` the IDE can find it and auto import it the same. so I guess maybe it's know which default I want to import by the filename?

Comment: It seems to depend on IDE, then, but probably it can either use the filename or recognise some common idioms. Is it required in your case to use `export default ..` and not e.g. `export const HomePage = ...`?

Comment: @Cerberus thank you. no it's only as I'm curious on how things works, and as `import HomePage from './HomePage'` looks better than `import {HomePage} from './HomePage'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`as` has 2 meanings. In ES6 modules, it can be a way to rename an import or export. In TypeScript, it is a typecast operator. I am going to assume you mean the first, specifically a way to rename an export.

Now take a look at this expression you suggested:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage) as HomePage;
```

Do you want to export it as `default` or do you want to export it as `HomePage`? When you export default, `default` is the export name. Given that, does this make sense to expect it to be called `HomePage`? You either export something that is called `default` or something that is called `HomePage`.

This table associates different export statement forms with the expected export name and local names:

[image]

For **importing**, though...

- If you are importing a default export, you have to **explicitly name** the import. Default exports will not automatically have a local name after importing. Example: `import express from "express"`. The local name does not matter. Could as well be `import banana from "express"`.
- If you are importing a named export, by default, the local name will be the same as the exported name. Example: If you have `export const x = 2`, then, you should import it as `import { x } from "module"`. You can also rename the import like this: `import { x as y } from "module".

[image]

The above tables are from the ES6 specs: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed & enriching information.
What I don't understand is - when you export as default (export name is "default")
when the IDE auto-import it to another file, how it's import it as `HomePage` (e.g `import HomePage from './HomePage'`) and not as default (`import default from './HomePage'`). is default export always imported by the IDE as the filename?

Comment: @ET-CS, I added a second part to the answer, in which I explain how imports work. Basically, for `default exports`, you name it as you wish, when you import them.

Comment: shame there is no `export * as v from mod`